# how to use ifelse on a data frame

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and I am trying to understand how `ifelse` works.

I tried with something simple like:

```
ifelse(mydataframe$col1==mydataframe$col2 ,
  mydataframe$newCol<-TRUE,
  mydataframe$newCol<-FALSE  
)
```

`mydataframe$col1` and `col2` are factors.
In this case my `newCol` will be always `FALSE`, which is wrong as I verified in this way:

```
mydataframe$newCol<- mydataframe[mydataframe$col1==mydataframe$col2]
```

I also don't want to use a `for` loop, which is usually slow for what I tried.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you mean just something like `mydataframe$newCol <- as.character(mydataframe$col1) == as.character(mydataframe$col2)`?

Comment: I think the `as.character()` might be unnecessary since (as I just found out) `==` on factors returns an error if the factors have different levels.

Answer (score 3):

`ifelse()` accepts return values as the 2nd and 3rd parameters (and you are writing assignments).

Try:

```
mydataframe$newCol <-
    with(mydataframe,
         ifelse(col1 == col2,
                TRUE,
                FALSE))
```

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact you don't need to use `ifelse`, `==` should suffice as in:

```
mydataframe$newCol <- with(mydataframe, col1 == col2)
```

It will return a boolean vector.

Comment: I would hope that the question shows a very-trimmed-down example, and that the questioner doesn't actually want this exact operation.

Comment: The question is about understanding how ifelse() works (first line) ;-)